# Failed to build iOS app Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): No such module 'flutter_callkit_incoming'

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, flutter-dependencies, codemagic

I am trying to run my flutter app for iOS part but there is a problem in the "flutter_callkit_incoming" module

the terminal error when run:
**flutter build ipa --release --export-options-plist /Users/builder/export_options.plist --flavor prod -t lib/main_prod.dart**

```
 Building with sound null safety 
Archiving com.mindscape.app...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 9PF4M6PSKX
Running pod install...                                             5.2s  
Running Xcode build...  
Xcode archive done. 78.6s  
Failed to build iOS app  
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): No such module 'flutter_callkit_incoming'  
 /Users/builder/clone/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:3:7
Encountered error while archiving for device.
```

I need to use flutter_callkit_incoming version "2.0.0+1"
I am using flutter 3.7.10
I am using code magic to build my iOS flutter application (as my device is windows)

**I found out that it is a flavor problem as when I run "--release --flavor dev" it works file but the problem happens when running "--release --flavor prod"**

The steps I followed

1. flutter clean
2. flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
   it returns:
   `flutter_callkit_incoming 2.0.0+1 from git`
3. pop install
   it returns:

   `Installing flutter_callkit_incoming (0.0.1)`
4. xcode builds
   it returns:

   `Failed to build iOS app` 
   `Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): No such module 'flutter_callkit_incoming'/Users/builder/clone/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:3:7`

here is the pubspec.yaml file:

> ```
> environment:
>   sdk: '>=2.18.6 <3.0.0'
>
> # Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
> # To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
> # consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
> # dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
> # the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
> # versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
> dependencies:
>   flutter:
>     sdk: flutter
>
>   flutter_localizations:
>     sdk: flutter
>   # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
>   # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
>
>   #  network
>   dio: ^5.1.0
>   dio_cache_interceptor: ^3.4.1
>   dio_cache_interceptor_hive_store: ^3.2.1
>   connectivity_plus: ^3.0.3
>   flutter_timezone: ^1.0.7
>
>   # firebase
>   firebase_messaging: ^14.4.0
>   firebase_core: ^2.9.0
>
>   # socket
>   socket_io_client: ^2.0.1
>
>   # agora
>   agora_rtc_engine: 6.1.0
>
>   # call kit
>   flutter_callkit_incoming:
>     git:
>       url: https://github.com/Mindsacpe/callkit-plugin.git
>       ref: main # branch name
>       version: 2.0.0+1
>   #  audio_session: ^0.1.13
>
>   # localization
>   easy_localization: ^3.0.3
>
>   # state management
>   path_provider: ^2.0.14
>   flutter_riverpod: ^2.3.2
>
>   # storage
>   shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
>   flutter_secure_storage: ^8.0.0
>
>
>   # permission
>   permission_handler: ^10.2.0
>
>   # ui - core
>   cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
>   device_info_plus: ^8.0.0
>   flutter_sim_country_code: ^0.1.2
>   fluttertoast: ^8.1.2
>   logger: ^1.1.0
>   shimmer: ^2.0.0
>   easy_debounce: ^2.0.3
>   tap_debouncer: ^2.1.0
>   flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.17
>   keyboard_actions: ^4.2.0
>   webview_flutter: ^4.2.0
>   flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1
>   carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
>   screen_protector: ^1.2.0
>   uuid: ^3.0.7
>
>
>   # notification
>   flutter_local_notifications: ^13.0.0
>
>   # authentication
>   sign_in_with_apple: ^4.3.0
>   google_sign_in: ^6.1.0
>   flutter_facebook_auth: 5.0.7
>   firebase_auth: ^4.4.0
>
>   # files and images
>   file_picker: ^5.2.4
>   image_cropper: ^3.0.1
>   image_picker: ^0.8.6
>   open_filex: ^4.3.2
>   extended_image: ^7.0.2
>   cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
>
>   # ui - otp
>   pin_code_fields: ^7.4.0
>
>   # Calender
>   table_calendar: ^3.0.8
>   add_2_calendar: ^2.2.3
>   easy_localization_generator: ^0.3.0
>
>
> dev_dependencies:
>   flutter_test:
>     sdk: flutter
>
>   # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
>   # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
>   # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
>   # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
>   # rules and activating additional ones.
>   flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
>
> # For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
> # following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
>
> # The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
> flutter:
>
>   # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
>   # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
>   # the material Icons class.
>   uses-material-design: true
>   generate: true
>
>   # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
>   assets:
>     - assets/translations/
>     - assets/images/
>     - assets/flags/
>     - assets/raw/
>     - assets/pngs/
>
>   # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
>   # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware
>
>   # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
>   # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
>
>   # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
>   # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
>   # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
>   # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
>   # example:
>   fonts:
>     - family: Abel
>       fonts:
>         - asset: assets/fonts/Abel-Regular.ttf
> #    - family: Poppins
> #      fonts:
> #        - asset: assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf
>   #
>   # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
>   # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
>
>
> flutter_native_splash:
>   color: "#44AA87"
>   image: assets/splash_images/splash_logo.png
>   branding: assets/splash_images/blank_bg.png
>   color_dark: "#44AA87"
>   image_dark: assets/splash_images/splash_logo.png
>   branding_dark: assets/splash_images/blank_bg.png
>
>   android_12:
>     image: assets/splash_images/splash_logo.png
>     icon_background_color: "#44AA87"
>     image_dark: assets/splash_images/splash_logo.png
>     icon_background_color_dark: "#44AA87"
>
>   web: false
>   android_gravity: center
>   ios_content_mode: center
> ```

here is the related part in pubspec.lock file:

> ```
> # Generated by pub
> # See https://dart.dev/tools/pub/glossary#lockfile
> packages:
>   flutter_callkit_incoming:
>     dependency: "direct main"
>     description:
>       path: "."
>       ref: main
>       resolved-ref: "66c127445afbd69813485a00e572d1e091c70ed6"
>       url: "https://github.com/Mindsacpe/callkit-plugin.git"
>     source: git
>     version: "2.0.0+1"
> sdks:
>   dart: ">=2.19.0 <3.0.0"
>   flutter: ">=3.7.0"
> ```

here is my pod file:

> ```
> # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
> platform :ios, '12.0'
> deployment_target = '12.0'
>
> # CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
> ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'
>
> project 'Runner', {
>   'Debug' => :debug,
>   'Profile' => :release,
>   'Release' => :release,
> }
>
> def flutter_root
>   generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
>   unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
>     raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
>   end
>
>   File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
>     matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
>     return matches[1].strip if matches
>   end
>   raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
> end
>
> require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)
>
> flutter_ios_podfile_setup
>
> target 'Runner' do
>   use_frameworks!
>   use_modular_headers!
>
>   flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
> end
>
> post_install do |installer|
>   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
>     flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
>     target.build_configurations.each do |config|
>     config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = deployment_target
>
>     config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
>             '$(inherited)',
>
>             ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
>             'PERMISSION_EVENTS=1',
>
>             ## dart: PermissionGroup.reminders
>             # 'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=1',
>
>             ## dart: PermissionGroup.contacts
>             # 'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=1',
>
>             ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
>             'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',
>
>             ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
>             'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1',
>
>             ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
>             # 'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=1',
>
>             ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
>             'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',
>
>             ## dart: PermissionGroup.audio session
>             'AUDIO_SESSION_MICROPHONE=1',
>
>             ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
>             # 'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',
>
>             ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
>             # 'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=1',
>
>             ## dart: PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary
>             'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=1',
>
>             ## dart: PermissionGroup.sensors
>             # 'PERMISSION_SENSORS=1',
>
>             ## dart: PermissionGroup.bluetooth
>             # 'PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH=1',
>
>             ## dart: PermissionGroup.appTrackingTransparency
>             # 'PERMISSION_APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY=1',
>
>             ## dart: PermissionGroup.criticalAlerts
>             # 'PERMISSION_CRITICAL_ALERTS=1'
>           ]
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```

here is my AppDelegate.swift file:

> ```
> import UIKit
> import PushKit
> import Flutter
> import flutter_callkit_incoming
>
>
> @UIApplicationMain
> @objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate, PKPushRegistryDelegate {
>
>     var methodOff = "UserOffline_Ios"
>     var methodOn = "UserOnline_Ios"
>     var channel = "com_mindscape_ios"
>     var flutterChannel  = FlutterMethodChannel()
>
>   override func application(
>     _ application: UIApplication,
>     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
>   ) -> Bool {
>     GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
>
>       //Setup VOIP
>       let mainQueue = DispatchQueue.main
>       let voipRegistry: PKPushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: mainQueue)
>       voipRegistry.delegate = self
>       voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushType.voIP]
>
>       if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
>           // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
>           UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
>           let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
>           UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
>                   options: authOptions,
>                   completionHandler: {_, _ in })
>       } else {
>           let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
>           UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
>           application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
>       }
>       application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
>
>       let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
>          flutterChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: channel, binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
>
>     return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
>   }
>     
>     // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground.
>      override func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
>              print("applicationWillTerminate called")
>          self.flutterChannel.invokeMethod(methodOff,arguments: "")
>     }
>     
>     // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
>     override func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
>         print("applicationWillResume called")
>         self.flutterChannel.invokeMethod(methodOn,arguments: "")
>     }
>     
> //    // Call back from Recent history
> //    override func application(_ application: UIApplication,
> //                              continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
> //                              restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
> //
> //        guard let handleObj = userActivity.handle else {
> //            return false
> //        }
> //
> //        guard let isVideo = userActivity.isVideo else {
> //            return false
> //        }
> //        let nameCaller = handleObj.getDecryptHandle()["nameCaller"] as? String ?? ""
> //        let handle = handleObj.getDecryptHandle()["handle"] as? String ?? ""
> //        let data = flutter_callkit_incoming.Data(id: UUID().uuidString, nameCaller: nameCaller, handle: handle, type: isVideo ? 1 : 0)
> //        //set more data...
> //        SwiftFlutterCallkitIncomingPlugin.sharedInstance?.startCall(data, fromPushKit: true)
> //
> //        return super.application(application, continue: userActivity, restorationHandler: restorationHandler)
> //    }
> //
>     // Handle updated push credentials
>     func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate credentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {
>
>         let deviceToken = credentials.token.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
>         print(deviceToken)
>         //Save deviceToken to your server
>         SwiftFlutterCallkitIncomingPlugin.sharedInstance?.setDevicePushTokenVoIP(deviceToken)
>     }
>     
>     func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didInvalidatePushTokenFor type: PKPushType) {
>         print("didInvalidatePushTokenFor")
>         SwiftFlutterCallkitIncomingPlugin.sharedInstance?.setDevicePushTokenVoIP("")
>     }
>     
>     func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
>         print("didReceiveIncomingPushWith")
>         guard type == .voIP else { return }
>
>         let id = payload.dictionaryPayload["id"] as? String ?? ""
>         let nameCaller = payload.dictionaryPayload["nameCaller"] as? String ?? ""
>         let handle = payload.dictionaryPayload["handle"] as? String ?? ""
>         let isVideo = payload.dictionaryPayload["isVideo"] as? Bool ?? false
>     
>         let data = flutter_callkit_incoming.Data(id: id, nameCaller: nameCaller, handle: handle, type: isVideo ? 1 : 0)
>         data.extra = payload.dictionaryPayload["extra"] as? NSDictionary ?? NSDictionary()
>         //set more data
>         //data.iconName = ...
>         //data.....
>         SwiftFlutterCallkitIncomingPlugin.sharedInstance?.showCallkitIncoming(data, fromPushKit: true)
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: do you have `Podfile.lock` file in the repo? if yes, you can try to delete it

Comment: No I don't have any Podfile.lock file

Comment: As I updated the question --> it is a flavor problem but I have no idea how to discover the root of the problem or solve it

Comment: Seems Cocoapods keeps showing `0.0.1` version because this is what is defined in the main branch on GitHub repo https://github.com/Mindsacpe/callkit-plugin/blob/main/ios/flutter_callkit_incoming.podspec

Can you see the same `0.0.1` version when you build `debug` flavor?

Comment: yes I see the same version in the debug dev flavor but then the build completed successfully with no errors, the issue happening in the Prod flavor only, I guess it is a configuration issue but I have no idea how to solve it, do you have any idea ??

Comment: I recommend to check Xcode settings for Release mode. Since you on Windows you need to connect to Codemagic build machine via VNC to use Xcode https://docs.codemagic.io/troubleshooting/accessing-builder-machine-via-ssh/